# How to search an encrypted attribute?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a sensitive attribute that must be encrypted at all times except during display (not my rule and I think it's overkill, but I must follow this rule). Additionally, the secret used to encrypt/decrypt this data must not be on or accessible through the database. So currently I have a session for the user that stores their encrypted password and decrypts this data when needed. However, now I need to find records by the encrypted attribute. I currently utilize ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor for encryption/decryption of the attribute. Here's the direction I think I should go to accomplish this:

```
decryptor = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(encrypted_password)
Family.where("decryptor.decrypt_and_verify(name) == ?", some_search_name)
```

Obviously the first side of that condition does not work as-is, but I need some way to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick Primer to Passwords in the DB**

This goes to show that encryption in the database is hard, and that you shouldn't do it unless you have thought carefully through your threat model and understand what all the tradeoffs are.  To be honest, I have serious doubts that an ORM can ever give you the security you need where you need encryption (for important knowledge reasons), and on PostgreSQL, it is particularly hard because of the possibility of key disclosure in the log files.  In general you really need to properly protect *both* encrypted and plain text with regard to passwords, so you really don't want a relational interface here but a functional one, with a query running under a totally different set of permissions.

Now, I can't tell in your example whether you are trying to protect passwords, but if you are, that's entirely the wrong way to go about it.  My example below is going to use MD5.  Now I am aware that MD5 is frowned upon by the crypto community because of the relatively short output, but it has the advantage in this case of not requiring pg_crypto to support and being likely stronger than attacking the password directly (in the context of short password strings, it is likely "good enough" particularly when combined with other measures).

Now what you want to do is this:  you want to salt the password, then hash it, and then search the hashed value.  The most performant way to do this would be to have a users table which does *not* include the password, but does include the salt, and a shadow table which includes the hashed password but not the user-accessible data.  The shadow table would be restricted to its owner and that owner would have access to the user table too.

Then you could write a function like this:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_userid_by_password(in_username text, in_password text)
 RETURNS INT LANGUAGE SQL AS
 $$
      SELECT user_id 
        FROM shadow
        JOIN users ON users.id = shadow.user_id
       WHERE users.username = $1 AND shadow.hashed_password = md5(users.salt || $2);
 $$ SECURITY DEFINER;
 ALTER FUNCTION get_userid_by_password(text, text) OWNER TO shadow_owner;
```

You would then have to drop to SQL to run this function (don't go through your ORM).  However you could index shadow.hashed_password and have it work with an index here (because the matching hash could be generated before scanning the table), and you are reasonably protected against SQL injections giving away the password hashes.  You still have to make sure that logging will not be generally enabled of these queries and there are a host of other things to  consider, but it gives you an idea of how best to manage passwords per se.  Alternatively in your ORM you could do something that would have a resulting SQL query like:

```
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = get_userid_by_password($username, $password)
```

(The above is pseudocode and intended only for illustration purposes.  If you use a raw query like that assembled as a text string you are asking for SQL injection.)

**What if it isn't a password?**

If you need reversible encryption, then you need to go further.  Note that in the example above, the index could be used because I was searching merely for an equality on the encrypted data.  Searching for an unencrypted data means that indexes are not usable.  If you index the unencrypted data then why are you encrypting it in the first place?  Also decryption does place burdens on the processor so it will be slow.

In all cases you need to carefully think through your threat model and ask how other vulnerabilities could make your passwords less secure.

Comment: MD5 is not frowned upon "because of the relatively short output", it's frowned upon because it is so fast to compute that it can be brute forced incredibly easily, and because it has known vulnerabilities.

Comment: Those vulnerabilities affect either non-password applications (if you limit passwords to a single cypher block size on input you are safe), and the speed is mitigated by protecting the hashes carefully as well.   Hence my point about other measures being important as well.

Comment: At any rate, it's not wise to disclose even hashed passwords to the world.

Comment: One improvement to your scheme would be to hash the password once at the application level, using say the username as a salt (since you haven't retrieved the random salt yet), and pass that into the SQL function (and hash it again), thus reducing the risk of logged SQL (someone reading the logs with no other access to the server then wouldn't have enough information to replay the login via the public UI).

Comment: That's a good point.  There are interesting tradeoffs there.  In general if this is authentication for only one application I would probably agree, since you are right, that it avoids logfile disclosure (which could be a topic all its own).

I am used to thinking about sharing security logic between applications so that the logic can be re-used.  In that case, handing it to the app increases your security perimeter in ways I would be concerned about.

Comment: That's why I suggested doing the hashing in *both* places, with different salts. Sending the first hash cannot be less secure than sending the plain text password, and computing it with only the username as salt requires no information that the app was not already processing.